# linux how to restart service using init

Tags: linux

On a linux ec2 not having systemd (using older version of amazon linux), am trying to setup init process to auto restart presto service.

```
[root@ip-1.1.1.1 init]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"

[root@ip-1.1.1.1 init]# cat /etc/inittab | grep -v '^#'
id:3:initdefault:
pr:2345:respawn:/etc/init.d/presto start
pr1:2345:respawn:/bin/su - root -c "service presto start" -- tried starting the service this way as well to see if it helps

[root@ip-1.1.1.1 init]# chkconfig --list presto
presto          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

[root@ip-1.1.1.1 init]# cat /etc/init/presto.conf 
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
respawn
respawn limit 2 5
```

Ran telinit u to reload init, killed running presto process but do not see the service respawning. Am I missing anything?

```
[root@ip-1.1.1.1 init]# telinit u
[root@ip-1.1.1.1 init]# service presto status
Getting status for presto 
Running as 29983
[root@ip-1.1.1.1 init]# kill -9 29983
-- waited for couple of mins, but dont see the service starting
[root@ip-1.1.1.1 init]# service presto status
Getting status for presto 
Not running
```

Comment: Which init daemon exactly is it in use? The configuration to respawn killed processes differs between them.

Comment: upstart - # [[ `/sbin/init --version` =~ upstart ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes

Answer (score 0):

In your OS used old initd to manage daemons. It's didn't provide any watchdog functionality, so if you kill your process you should restart it manually. Use `service presto restart` or `service presto condrestart`.